# Firebase app check feature works with realtime database but not with cloud storage

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage, recaptcha-v3, firebase-app-check

I implemented firebase app check feature for a web application using Google Recaptcha v3 as described in the documents. But when I look at console metrics there I can see verified requests of realtime database while all other requests are still unverified for cloud storage.
[image]
[image: firebase-app check - storage metrics]

I tested it on the same pages. Web app reads data from realtime database and then downloads pictures from cloud storage.

What could be the reason for this?

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/app-check';
import 'firebase/database';
import config from './firebaseServiceConfig';

firebase.initializeApp(config);

this.appCheck = firebase.appCheck();
this.realtimeDB = firebase.database();
this.storage = firebase.storage();
this.appCheck.activate(process.env.REACT_APP_RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY);
```

Comment: Did you solve it? I'm getting a similar problem - Cloud Firestore gets verified requests but the storage keeps getting unverified ones